# Tcl Programming using string

Tags: string, tcl

I want to write a TCL program for a given input string "**Hello I Am Fine**" , whose output must be: "**Fine Am I Hello**"

Also Want to know, how to find the last element within a list of elements?
Eg: `[list 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100]`
-- So from this list i want to use the last element.

Thanks.

Comment: You will benefit from the [Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need the last element of a list, you can access it with

```
lindex $list end
```

If you want to know the index of the last element, use

```
expr {[llength $list] - 1}
```

If you want to reverse a list, use

```
set newList [lreverse $list]
```

Simple as that.

And for the the Input/Output thing, I suggest first `split` it into a list, then reverse it, and `join` the result again. I leave it to you as exercise.